# Pivot: Start with no tabs selected

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Using Fabric React, I am working on a component that uses the `Pivot` element.

When the component is first shown, no tabs should be selected, and some content must be shown under the tab headers. Once a tab is clicked, related content will be shown there.

The example "No Pivots Selected" in the [documentation page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/#/controls/web/pivot) is pretty close to what I want. In the first render, no tabs are selected. I am thinking that the prop `selectedKey={null}` should give that result.

Following code is based on that example, yet even when the component is shown first time, a tab (first one) is shown as selected (e.g. there is a blue underline under it).

What is the problem?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Pivot, PivotItem } from "office-ui-fabric-react";

export interface MainProps {}

export const Main: React.FC<MainProps> = () => {
  const [selectedKey, setSelectedKey] = React.useState(null);

  const pivotItems: { [key: string]: React.ReactElement<any> } = {
    Settings: <div>Settings</div>,
    Controls: <div>Controls</div>
  };
  const _getTabId = (itemKey: string): string => {
    return `ShapeColorPivot_${itemKey}`;
  };

  const _handleLinkClick = (item: PivotItem): void => {
    setSelectedKey(item.props.itemKey);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Pivot
        headersOnly
        selectedKey={selectedKey}
        getTabId={_getTabId}
        onLinkClick={_handleLinkClick}
        style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      >
        {Object.keys(pivotItems).map(name => (
          <PivotItem
            key={`pivotItemKey_${name}`}
            headerText={name}
            itemKey={name}
          />
        ))}
      </Pivot>
      {selectedKey ? pivotItems[selectedKey] : <div>Start</div>}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick codepen using

```
    <Pivot selectedKey={null} >
```

and it worked just fine. Are you sure you're on the most recent version of Fabric?

Comment: Yes, upgrading to a higher version solved the default selection problem.